# discord.py how to improve show avatar command that it'll show not only mentioned member but your too

Tags: discord.py

i want to improve this command that when you write it without mention, it'll show your avatar, and if with menthion it will show mentioned person avatar, but i don't know how to do it correctly, i tried using if error show `ctx.author.avatar_url` but it didn’t work out for me, here is my code that show only mentioned member av

```
@commands.command( aliases = ['av'] )
async def showavatar( self, ctx, member: discord.Member ):
        await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )
        emb = discord.Embed( color = discord.Color.green() )
        emb.set_image( url = member.avatar_url )
        await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

EDITED

error - discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError Command raised an exception: AttributeError:'NoneType'object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

tryed to put self before member.avatar_url but it doesn't help

```
@commands.command( aliases = ['av'] )
    async def showavatar( self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None ):
        await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )
        emb = discord.Embed( color = discord.Color.green() )
        emb.set_image( url = member.avatar_url )
        await ctx.send( embed = emb )
        if member is None:
            member = author.avatar_url
            emb = discord.Embed( color = discord.Color.green() )
            emb.set_image( url = member )
            await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

Comment: Instead of purging the channel, you should delete the message. `ctx.message.delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set a default value of `None` to `member` and inside the command check for it, if the `member` variable is `None` then `member = ctx.author`

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['av'])
async def showavatar(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green())
    emb.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, next time please be more careful, you were only supposed to copy and paste your code where the three dots were.